# Correct Translation Manager Email Notification from Event System examples?

Tags: translation-manager, sites-9.1

Functionally, I can see that we can configure [email addresses to be notified when Translation Manager jobs are sent per the documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/689562/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/configuring-email-notifications).

However, the example in the Sites 9.1 documentation mentions the `ErrorEmailNotificationsPlugin.cs` sample plugin.

Is this C# example following the old Translation Manager plugin approach?

If not, is there a different example for the Event System? Before recommending possible customization I want to be sure we're following the newer API (Event System for Translation Manager rather than plugin approach). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customer should use Event System approach.
Old Translation Manager Plugin system is deprecated for many years.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;

using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.TranslationManager.V2;
using Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.EventSystem.Events;

namespace Examples.V1
{
    [TcmExtension("TranslationManagerExamples.ErrorEmailNotifications")]
    public class ErrorEmailNotifications : TcmExtension
    {
        private const string TemplateFolderPath = "[Path to email template file]";
        private const string SmtpSendAddress = "[Smtp send address]";
        private const string SmtpReplyAddress = "[Smtp reply address]";
        private const string SmtpServerUrl = "[Smtp server url]";
        private const int SmtpPort = 25;
        private const int SmtpConnectionTimeoutSeconds = 20;
        private const string SmtpUserName = "[Smtp user name]";
        private const string SmtpPassword = "[Smtp user password]";

        public ErrorEmailNotifications()
        {
            // Subscribe on TranslationJob error event
            EventSystem.Subscribe<ITranslationJob, IErrorEventArgs>(OnTranslationJobError, EventPhases.Initiated, EventSubscriptionOrder.Normal);
        }

        private void OnTranslationJobError(ITranslationJob job, IErrorEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!SendEmailNotification(job, e))
                {
                    return;
                }

                // Read template values
                string templateFile = Path.Combine(TemplateFolderPath, "ErrorEmailTemplate.xml");
                string subject = null;
                string body = null;
                string emailAddress = null;
                bool isText = true;
                if (File.Exists(templateFile))
                {
                    XmlDocument template = new XmlDocument();
                    template.Load(templateFile);
                    XmlNode emailAddressNode = template.SelectSingleNode("//email");
                    if (emailAddressNode != null)
                    {
                        emailAddress = emailAddressNode.InnerText;
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress))
                    {
                        job.TmSession.Log(false, "Unable to send error notification emails, the email address is not defined");
                        return;
                    }
                    XmlNode subjectElement = template.SelectSingleNode("//subject");
                    if (subjectElement != null)
                    {
                        subject = subjectElement.InnerText;
                    }
                    isText = template.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("type") == "text";
                    XmlNode bodyElement = template.SelectSingleNode("//body");
                    if (bodyElement != null)
                    {
                        body = ReplacePlaceholders(bodyElement.InnerText, e, isText);
                    }
                }
                // Default values if missing from the template
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject))
                {
                    subject = "Translation error notification";
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
                {
                    isText = true;
                    body = e.ErrorDetails.ExceptionDetails.ToString();
                }
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(SmtpSendAddress, emailAddress, subject, body);
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = !isText;
                mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(SmtpReplyAddress));

                job.TmSession.Log(false, "Sending error notification email to: " + emailAddress);
                SmtpClient smtpClient = GetSmtpClient();
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                job.TmSession.Log(ex);
            }
        }

        private string ReplacePlaceholders(string source, IErrorEventArgs e, bool isText)
        {
            string result = source;
            var exceptionDetails = e.ErrorDetails.ExceptionDetails;

            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_exceptionMessage", exceptionDetails.Message, string.Empty, isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_exceptionDetails", exceptionDetails.ToString(), string.Empty, isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_jobId", e.ErrorDetails.JobId.ToString(), "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_jobTitle", e.ErrorDetails.JobTitle, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_tmsJobId", e.ErrorDetails.TmsJobId, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_tcmItemCurrentTargetTitle", e.ErrorDetails.TcmItemCurrentTargetTitle, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_tcmItemNewTargetTitle", e.ErrorDetails.TcmItemNewTargetTitle, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_tcmItemSourceTitle", e.ErrorDetails.TcmItemSourceTitle, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_tcmItemSourceUri", e.ErrorDetails.TcmItemSourceUri, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_tcmItemTargetUri", e.ErrorDetails.TcmItemTargetUri, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_tmsItemId", e.ErrorDetails.TmsItemId, "n/a", isText);
            result = ReplacePlaceholder(result, "_targetLanguageId", e.ErrorDetails.TargetLanguageId, "n/a", isText);
            return result;
        }

        private string ReplacePlaceholder(string source, string key, string value, string defaultValue, bool isText)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                value = defaultValue;
            }
            if (!isText)
            {
                value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
            }
            return source.Replace("<" + key + "/>", value);
        }

        private bool SendEmailNotification(ITranslationJob job, IErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ErrorDetails.Severity != ErrorSeverity.Error)
            {
                // Only send email for critical problems
                return false;
            }

            if (job.Id == 0)
            {
                // The error is not related to a specific Translation Job, but is a more general failure. It
                // could for example happen if the connection to TMS is down.
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private SmtpClient GetSmtpClient()
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpServerUrl, SmtpPort);
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Timeout = SmtpConnectionTimeoutSeconds * 1000;

            // Set credentials if needed
            // The SmtpClient will query the mail server for NTLM support and use it if present
            // (uncomment next line if you need to set credentials)
            
            //smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUserName, SmtpPassword);

            return smtpClient;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the documentation needs updating. Looking in the Installation Media, theres now an **EventHandlers** folder with a **ErrorEmailNotifications.cs** file which using the Event System and not the old plug-in approach.

```
[TcmExtension("TranslationManagerExamples.ErrorEmailNotifications")]
public class ErrorEmailNotifications : TcmExtension
{
    private const string TemplateFolderPath = "[Path to email template file]";
    private const string SmtpSendAddress = "[Smtp send address]";
    private const string SmtpReplyAddress = "[Smtp reply address]";
    private const string SmtpServerUrl = "[Smtp server url]";
    private const int SmtpPort = 25;
    private const int SmtpConnectionTimeoutSeconds = 20;
    private const string SmtpUserName = "[Smtp user name]";
    private const string SmtpPassword = "[Smtp user password]";

    public ErrorEmailNotifications()
    {
        // Subscribe on TranslationJob error event
        EventSystem.Subscribe<ITranslationJob, IErrorEventArgs>(OnTranslationJobError, EventPhases.Initiated, EventSubscriptionOrder.Normal);
    }
```